# create file only if specific method is being called in PHP code?

Tags: php, file, methods

How to create file only is specific method is called in the code.

suppose say,

```
<?php

function foo(){
}
function foo1() {
}

?>
```

I want to create a file only if method foo1() was called. I dont want to create the file from constructor because this code might run without foo1() not being called(will unnecessarily create file). Also i might call foo1() multiple times in a single run but file should be created only once and I will add date into file.

Hope I am clear. How to do that?

Comment: So you put your file creation code if foo1(), but test if the file already exists before creating it... what's the problem?

Comment: thanks, but how to check if file already exists? any sample code would be helpfule. @MarkBaker

Comment: `file_exists('file_sting_including%20Directories');`

Answer (score 2):

Check the existence of the file before create it.

```
function foo1() {
    $path = '/foo/bar/my_file.txt';

    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        // Create your file here
    }

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

Put your creation code in `foo1()`, you could then either ask the file if it already exists or keep your own boolean flag.  I would prefer the first option.